# I accidentally installed Lubuntu on a windows 32-bit machine when the Lubuntu was 64-bit

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I accidentally installed Lubuntu on Windows 32-bit when the Lubuntu installer was 64-bit and I can't exit the boot setup, I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGR_VNwUfzk) and I can't exit the installer.

I have an old Fujitsu laptop and I don't what to do, The installer gives me an error and I don't know how to exit the boot setup and start Windows 7 that was already installed, It gives me this error:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU 
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU
```

And I don't know how to exit the setup, and I just want to run Windows 7 on my computer.

Comment: You've not provided any Lubuntu release details; but Lubuntu doesn't have a supported *i386* or 32-bit x86 release any more, in fact no Ubuntu system does (*the last reached EOL in May 2023*).  You're hardware likely isn't supported; as *amd64* only is supported now by Lubuntu.

Comment: If Lubuntu wasn't installed (*where it reads like it never actually booted as you don't have the required amd64 processor, only having i686*), just turn the machine off, eject your installation media (*USB drive with Lubuntu*), and when you turn your machine back on it should be untouched on next boot.

Comment: the instalation media is in the harddrive,what do i do,its different from C: ,its  F:

Answer (score 2):

Steps 1 and 2 answer the main question. Steps 3-5 provide additional information and are optional.

1. Power off the computer by manually holding down the power button.
2. Safely remove the Lubuntu 64-bit installer installation media.
3. Lubuntu 19.04 and later are available for 64-bit architecture only.  To install Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit, just prepare the Lubuntu 18.04 32-bit USB installation media and install it without any install upgrades or install third-party packages options selected during installation.
4. Reboot when the installation is complete.
5. To upgrade or install software in Lubuntu 18.04 follow the instructions in the answers to [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/).